# Reflection of light by edges and corners of mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection

Suppose I have a point object placed between mirrors inclined at angle $\theta$ with each other. What will happen to the ray that strikes the junction point of these mirrors? I'm looking for a mathematical solution.

Comment: Mathematically (and in planar optics) that is a single undefined ray. In physics a single ray doesn't matter since it can't carry a finite amount of energy, hence it doesn't "show". If you want to know what happens to the diffraction pattern, which is a more realistic model of the actual physics, that's probably quite interesting: angled mirrors will make two virtual images from a single point source, i.e. the angled mirror should cause a diffraction diagram similar to that of a "double hole" (one dimensional version of the "double slit"). Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ FlatterMann: The correlation of the Double Slit Experiment with inclined mirrors, how do you figure that?

Comment: https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/two-plane-mirrors-are-at-right-angles-to-each-class-12-physics-cbse-5f9401e5944a4d138a9f8a70 Multiple virtual images in an angled mirror (there can be more than two, I just picked the case of a shallow angle and small mirror). For small angles there will be two virtual images that are "close" to each other, which makes for a nice diffraction pattern. Your case makes for a many slit pattern, actually, since you are asking about an object between two mirrors, so there will potentially a lot of mirror images. I didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about the ray that strikes the join, but a ray is not a physical object. Instead it is just a direction i.e. it is the normal to the light wavefront.

Suppose we draw the point source, with the wavefronts radiating outwards from it, and the two mirrors joined as you describe. And we'll assume ideal mirrors so the join is a line with zero width where the angle of the mirror changed discontinuously.

[image: Mirror]

The light from the source to the left of the vertical dashed line (e.g. ray $A$) will reflect of the left mirror, and the light to the right of the dashed line (e.g. ray $C$) will reflect off the right mirror, but the question is what happens to the light that travels exactly along the vertical dashed line i.e. the ray $B$?

Physically the answer is simply that there is no light travelling in exactly the vertical direction. The energy of light travelling within some solid angle $\Omega$ is given by:

$$I(\Omega) = I_0 \frac{\Omega}{4\pi} $$

where $I_0$ is the total intensity of the source. But the line between the (ideal) mirrors has zero width so it subtends zero solid angle and hence $\Omega = 0$. That means the intensity of the light striking the join is zero i.e.

**No light strikes the join between the mirrors**

So we can draw the ray $B$ that strikes the join, but this ray doesn't represent any light. It's just a direction not actually any light.

Although it makes no physical sense, we can still ask what happens mathematically, and the answer is that it is undefined because the angle of the mirror is undefined at the join. We could write the mirror as a mathematical function:

$$ y = a|x| $$

and the angle of the line is then just $dy/dx$, so it is $-a$ for $x\lt0$ and $+a$ for $x\gt0$, but at $x=0$ the gradient is undefined since at the point $dy/dx$ changes discontinuously.